# Why add method invoked from ActionListener class doesn't add an element to collection? Java

Tags: java, swing

Ok, here's my GUI class (shorted)

```
public class GUI {
private DataContainer dataContainer;

public GUI(DataContainer dataContainer){
    this.dataContainer = dataContainer;
    initGUI();
}

class RegisterListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String message;
        String firstName = registerPanelFirstNameTextField.getText();
        String lastName = registerPanelLastNameTextField.getText();
        String login = registerPanelLoginTextField.getName();
        String password = registerPanelPasswordTextField.getText();
        String adress = registerPanelAdressTextField.getText();
        Client client = new Client(firstName, lastName, login, password, adress);
        boolean registerCheck = dataContainer.registerClient(client);
        if (registerCheck) {
            message = "SUCCES!";
        } else {
            message = "FAILURE!";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message);
    }
}
```

And here's my DataContainer class (also shorted):

```
public class DataContainer implements Subject {

public boolean workingStatus = true;
private List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Auction> auctionList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Observer> observersList = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean registerClient(Client client) {
    String testLogin = client.getLogin();
    boolean isClientOnList = isClientOnList(testLogin);
    if (isClientOnList) {
        return false;
    } else {
        addClientToList(client);
        return true;
    }
}

private void addClientToList(Client client) {
    clientList.add(client);
    System.out.println(clientList);
}
```

And here's my question - why method invoked from register listener gives empty collection. SysOut prints `[null]`. I have used JUnit and reflection to directly test `addClientToList()`, and it works, but it simply doesn't when clicking the button. And yes, in my class I created new `DataContainer` object, and passed it to GUI constructor.

Comment: Did you debug? Are you sure that `isClientOnList` is false? Are you sure that `client` is non-null? Note that `[null]` is not an empty collection, but a collection with one element which is `null`. Is this your actual code? Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: It's nice that you shortened the code, but that doesn't mean to sacrifice completeness

Answer (score 0):

Oh RIGHT! Found this little guy. Problem was here:

```
String login = registerPanelLoginTextField.getName();
```

and it should be:

```
String login = registerPanelLoginTextField.getText();
```